# Any criteria on selecting the startup form?

Tags: vb.net, startup, app-startup

**Question:**

In .NET do you have any criteria that qualifies a certain form to be the startup form?

**Example:**

For example, if I have a basic calculator program and it has 3 forms
   namely  frmConfig, frmCalculator and frmProfile.

- `frmConfig` - The settings page, includes whether I should automatically round off or  out put the whole decimals, etc.
- `frmCalculator` - The main page, the calculator itself where you can do    all the calculations that you want.
- `frmProfile` - The login page, you can see the history of your    calculations here.

**Notes:**

1. From that 3 different kinds of forms how do I properly choose the
   startup form?
2. Does it mean that the startup form should `always` be the first form to see
   when the application is running?

   `Because for example I can make the frmConfig as the startup form then on OnLoad event of it it will hide itself then open the frmCalculator because frmCalculator depends on frmConfig's default setting.`
3. To make this question not broad I am looking for the most common way of setting up the startup form, maybe there is a standard way?

Comment: You can also start the app from a Sub Main.  Since you describe `frmCalculator` as *The main page* it seems logical to use that as the "MainForm" or for the app msg pump.  My most common way is Sub Main so the app can do whatever it needs to before any form shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your startup form by accessing the **My Project** from the Solution Explorer, then going to the **Application** page

[Image: Choosing startup form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CzxA.png)